# Replace space with character in a string except for words between quotes with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

In my web application I implemented a **search functionality** with a textbox and buttons with a jQuery onclick event handler attached. Each button triggers a different search handler.

HTML

```
<input id="searchText" placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="text" />

<div id="searchLinksBar">
    <a href="/search">All</a>
    <a href="/search/downloads">Downloads</a>
    <a href="/search/kb">Knowledge Base</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#searchLinksBar a").click(function() {
     //Get content from the selected anchor
     var categoryURL = $(this).attr("href");

     //Get search string
     var searchText = $("#searchText").val();
     var searchString = ToQueryString(searchText);

     //Check if the search bar is filled 
     if(searchString.trim()){
       categoryURL = categoryURL + "&str="
     }

     //Attach the two strings to get our full URL
     var searchUrl = categoryURL + searchString;


     window.location.href = searchUrl;
     return false;
})
});

function ToQueryString(text) {
  return text.replace(/ /g, "+");
}
```

The search works great except when a user wants to search an exact phrase by including several words within quotes. There shouldn't be the '+' sign between words within quotes, otherwise the handler does not work as expected. I might think of a solution by using regular expressions or use the concat and split function (see below) to divide words within quotes from those with quotes and place in a array but maybe there is a more elegant solution

```
var phrases = [].concat.apply([], text.split('"').map(function(v,i){
     return i%2 ? '"'+v+'"' : v.split(' ')
})).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: *"There shouldn't be the '+' sign between words within quotes, otherwise the handler does not work as expected."* Then the handler is broken, and you should fix *that* rather than try to pre-process the result to work around it.

Comment: Due respect, your `ToQueryString` is nothing remotely like a "to query string" function, there are ***lots*** of other things you need to do to correctly send user-entered text as a URI-encoded parameter, which is what you're doing above. Fortunately for you, there's already something that does it: `encodeURIComponent`: http://pastie.org/9805487

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In order to focus on the scope of the question I omitted that the handler expects the underscore to separate words between quotes. For the same reason I simplified the ToQueryString function

Comment: Frankly, that doesn't make a lot of sense, it's just asking for help presenting inaccurate information. But why are you reinventing the wheel? Have your handler expect URI-encoded data (your server probably handles it for you) and correctly URI-encode the data. Done.

Comment: Simply because I have no control on the handler :)